# Visual Basic - How to save an image that is in the first column of a listview control?

Tags: vb.net, listview

Have a listview object with some columns and some rows. The first one has an image for each line (different images). I want to save each image from each row. The filename doesn't matter (could be `imgyyyyMMddHHmmss.jpg`, for example). struggling to get the image. The following code does not work (the listview item cannot be converted to string).

Any clues?

Thanks

```
    Dim tmpIndex1 As Integer
    Dim tmpImage As Image

    For tmpIndex = 0 To listView1.Items.Count
        tmpImage = lsvAddOrderItems.Items(tmpIndex1)
        tmpImage.Save()
    Next
```

Comment: How did that image end up in there? Was it by accident :) Could it be inside an ImageList? How did you load the ImageLIst? Btw, which kind ListView? What UI platform are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView control cannot contain an Image object within one of its Items.
If you want to add images to a ListView you must associate an ImageList to the ListView control.
Then to your ImageListControl load the images with its Key

Once you have all your images inside your ImageListControl, you will fill your items with your ListViewControl with the imageKey of your ImageListControl.

Then you must change your code to:

```
For tmpIndex = 0 To listView1.Items.Count
    tmpImage = ImageListControl.Images(lsvAddOrderItems.Items(tmpIndex1).ImageKey)
    tmpImage.Save()
Next
```

This way the conversion will not fail.

Comment: Thanks. I am not the one that wrote the program. Took me a while to find the imagelist where the images were coming from (programmatically). That solved my issue.